# Matplotlib xtick appends .%f after %H:%M%:S on chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

EDIT: Matplotlib version is 1.4.2, 
      Numpy version is 1.8.2

I am creating a graph from a csv file that has the following format

```
08:21:05,41.0
08:22:05,41.0
08:23:05,41.0
```

The first column is the time (of course) and the second column is a centimetre measurement.

I am updating an application I wrote to measure sump pit waterlevel activity to Python3 which requires converting
the date from bytes to str as it was throwing an error.  Accepted bytes fine under Python2.

The graph gets created with the following code;

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

def bytesdate2str(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    '''Convert strpdate2num from bytes to string as required in Python3.

    This is a workaround as described in the following tread;
    https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4126/

    Credit to github user cimarronm for this workaround.
    '''

    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)

    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

def graph(csv_file, filename, bytes2str):
    '''Create a line graph from a two column csv file.'''

    unit = 'metric'
    date, value = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                             converters={0: bytes2str}
                             )
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3.5))
    fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='white', frameon=False)
    rcParams.update({'font.size': 9})
    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value, ls='solid', linewidth=2, color='#FB921D',
                  fmt=':'
                  )
    title = "Sump Pit Water Level {}".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
    title_set = plt.title(title)
    title_set.set_y(1.09)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.86)

    if unit == 'imperial':
        plt.ylabel('inches')
    if unit == 'metric':
        plt.ylabel('centimeters')

    plt.xlabel('Time of Day')
    plt.xticks(rotation=30)
    plt.grid(True, color='#ECE5DE', linestyle='solid')
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', bottom='off', top='off')
    plt.tick_params(axis='y', left='off', right='off')
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi=72)


csv_file = "file.csv"
filename = "today.png"

bytes2str = bytesdate2str('%H:%M:%S')
graph(csv_file, filename, bytes2str)
```

Using matplotlib for Python 3 I had to convert the date from bytes to str which is what the function bytesdate2str does.
This was a workaround that another github user had written in an issues thread.  I gave it a try and it does indeed create the graph fine now.

However the time on the x axis now appends .%f to the end.  I have been able to find some documentation on the matplotlib site around date formatting
but I am having trouble figuring out how to remove that .%f which I presume represents a float.

Here is what the xticks looked like before under Python2
[image: Good xticks image]

Here is what the xticks looks like after converting from bytes to str
[image: Bad xticks image]

How do I remove %f from the end of the time? This is the only thing I have used matplotlib for and am a novice when it comes
to the package. I have banged my head long enough.  Appreciate any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on Matplotlibs Github repo and the answer was provided by github user tacaswell.

Details of fix at the following link;

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6037#issuecomment-186822699

Answer (score 0):

`%f` is the microseconds field in the datetime module. I think something is wrong with your `bytes2str = bytesdate2str('%H:%M:%S')`